# Captcha fails on Safari 14.0.1 Big Sur

Tags: bug, captcha, safari

When I try to solve [the captcha](https://stackoverflow.com/captcha) on Safari 14.0.1 (on Big Sur), it gets stuck on the loading spinner when I tap the checkbox.

I see the following error multiple times in the console:

> The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''strict-dynamic''. It will be ignored.

Comment: Can't reproduce (also tested with Firefox and Chrome on Big Sur and both of those work fine too). Possibly some problem with your machine/browser specifically?

Comment: I found how to replicate: enable https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/prevent-cross-site-tracking-sfri40732/mac and then at least on first go on the page without previous cookies this fails.